# Difference between $map{$string} and $map->{$string} in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, dictionary

I have a map structure in Perl, that I'm getting from some utility. The dump of which looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'A0' => 'me_one',
  'A2' => 'me_two',
  'A6' => 'me_six'
}
```

I want to search if a particular key exists in the map. Say I would like to know if `A4` is in the map.

Now if I use `if (exists $map{'A4'})`, I get an error during build, at `$map{`.

And if I use `if (exists $map->{'A4'})`, I get no error, and I get the desired result. However everywhere I search on the internet, to check if a key exists in a map, the syntax in Perl is `if (exists $map{key})`

Now my inference is that what I get from utility is not a map, though still looks like a map to me from the dump. Any one has an idea what's going on? Thank you.

**Edit:** Thanks to @raina77ow's answer. Adding this to further his explanation.

```
my %map;
print $map{key};
my $map_ref = \%map; # The reference was what the utility was returning
print $map_ref->{key};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$map{key}` line is used when you address a specific element of *hash* `%map`. For example:

```
my %map = (
  a => 'a',
  b => 'b'
);
print $map{a}; # 'a'
```

The `$map->{key}` line is used when you address a specific element of *hashref* `$map`. `->` operator is used specifically to 'deference' a reference.

```
my $map_ref = {
  a => 'a',
  b => 'b'
};
print $map_ref->{a}; # 'a'
```

Note that in the first case the regular parenthesis are used, in the second case it's curly brackets (to define so-called `anonymous hash`).

Comment: Thanks. That explains well. :). I will make a small addition to your answer before accepting it.